# MVC/C#: DropDownListFor not selecting 'selected' item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

ok, I have a situation where I need to have multiple DDLs of 'BayTypes' that use the same dictionary, which isn't a problem. One DDL for each of 'n' BayOptions. I'm passing a dictionary to my view as 'BayTypes' like this:

(Controller)

```
var bayTypes = _bayTypeRepository.GetBayTypes().ToList();
property.BayTypes = bayTypes.ToDictionary(g => g.Name, g => g.BayTypeGuid.ToString());
```

(View)

```
var overrideValue = item.BayTypeOverride ? item.BayTypeOverrideValue.BayTypeGuid.ToString() : string.Empty;
var result = (from x in Model.BayTypes
              select new SelectListItem()
                  {
                  Text = x.Key,
                  Value = x.Value,
                  Selected = x.Value == overrideValue <-- ***this is working***
                  });
if (item.BayTypeOverride == true)
    {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BayTypes, result, new { @Name = "BayOptionsToSubmit[" + aCounter + "].BayTypeOverrideValue" })
    }
    else
    {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BayTypes, result, new { @Name = "BayOptionsToSubmit[" + aCounter + "].BayTypeOverrideValue", @style = "display:none;" })
    }
```

The correct item IS getting selected in the 'result' object. If I step through, and watch 'result', I can see that 'Selected = true' for the right one... but it's not selecting in the DDLFor when it renders...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... Changed to a .DropDownList (no 'For') and passed in the 'name' as the 'result' var created earlier. Works.

```
var overrideValue = item.BayTypeOverride ? item.BayTypeOverrideValue.BayTypeGuid.ToString() : string.Empty;
var result = (from x in Model.BayTypes
              select new SelectListItem()
              {
                Text = x.Key,
                Value = x.Value,
                Selected = x.Value == overrideValue
               });
               if (item.BayTypeOverride)
               {
                @Html.DropDownList("result", result, htmlAttributes: new { @Name = "BayOptionsToSubmit[" + aCounter + "].BayTypeOverrideValue" })
               }
               else
               {
                @Html.DropDownList("result", result, htmlAttributes: new { @Name = "BayOptionsToSubmit[" + aCounter + "].BayTypeOverrideValue", @style = "display:none;" })
                                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, what determines the "selected" item in a drop down is `ModelState`, not the `SelectListItem.Selected` property. `ModelState` is composed from the following sources: `Request`, `ViewData`, `ViewBag`, and finally `Model`.

Check the values of `Request["BayTypes"]`, `ViewData["BayTypes"]`, `ViewBag.BayTypes`, and `Model.BayTypes`. If any of those has a different value from what you're expecting to be selected, that's your problem, particularly if the value is not even in the ballpark.

For example, a common cause of this is developers storing their actual select list choices in something like `ViewBag.Foo` and then trying to apply that to a dropdown bound to `Model.Foo`. The select list itself at that point becomes the selected item in `ModelState`, rather than the one particular value you selected.

Comment: I have this working in a slightly different fashion elsewhere in this solution utilizing the Viewbag pattern you describe above, but it works..lol This is not a bound field. I'm only passing in a dictionary, not a list of 'BayType' objects, and via a Viewmodel I'm re-mapping back to the BayType/BayOptions objects. I'll check the values you suggest reviewing. Although you don't mention a 'fix'. Thanks.

Comment: The "fix" is dependent on what you find. For example, if you're setting something into a similarly named `ViewBag` property, you can just change the name of that property. However, if you're getting something from a request parameter, you may need to adapt in a different way. It all depends.

Comment: the problem is really in the fact that there are 'n' BayOptions so I can't set the selected in the controller, it must be set in the view per BayOption.